# Twitter URL encoding. Getting error when placing UK Currency sign in URL?

Tags: url, twitter, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to setup a retweet button with some pre-written post text.
However I need to place a pound sign in like so:

£50k

I've search the web and for the UK currency sign I've been told it is supposed to be replaced with the code: `%a3`

However when I attempt to click on the link I get the error message:

"Invalid Unicode value in one or more parameters"

This is the document declaration at the top of the html page I'm using:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping it as `&pound;` usually this is how you would do it when using HTML. You can also do it using `&#163;`

Answer (score 0):

Would add to the above answer that sometimes you might need to use `%C2%A3`to get it to work.  Where `%A3` is a £ and the preceding character prevents it from being mis-read by some scripts.